# use of measurements for patients who withdrew from study in multilevel model

Tags: mixed-model, missing-data

I am working on a study where I have pre and post measurements and am interested in the impact of a treatment. I plan to use multilevel models. My question: Some subjects withdrew from the study and I don’t currently have their data (so I can’t see how many measurements they had, etc). Is it worth it to get their data to include in the analysis? My understanding is that with multilevel models, one should include everyone with at least 1 measurement. Is that correct – even if they only have a pre measurement?

thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed in multilevel models, you should all subjects in your study even if they have a single measurement. This would ensure that for a correctly specified model, the results you obtained are valid under the missing at random assumption. In case you would exclude subjects with one measurement the results would not only be less efficient (i.e., you're using less information) but also only valid under the more stringent missing completely at random assumption.

Moreover, if it would be at all possible to recover data that you currently do not have, this would always be better than having to work with incomplete data.

Comment: In contrast, a lot of randomized trials that I've reviewed seem to retain complete cases only and do ANOVA, which completely removes information on those who dropped out midway, and likely leads to bias. I am not sure I agree with retaining subjects with only a single valid measurement; in context, this probably means they had a pre-intervention measurement only. It does appear to be accepted practice to drop these observations; this is considered to be modified intent to treat. Obviously, the more of these patients there are, the more problematic.